# C# WMI Win32_ScheduledJob properties

Tags: c#, wmi, scheduled-tasks

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions(); 
connOptions.Username = _username; 
connOptions.Password = _password; 
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(_server, connOptions);
manScope.Connect();
ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_ScheduledJob");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create"); 
inParams["Name"] = "TESTER"; 
inParams["Owner"] = "Tester";
inParams["Command"] = command;
inParams["StartTime"] = "********171000.000000-300";
```

I'm tyring to connect to a remote system to create a scheduled task. I can create the scheduled tasks, but its being created with user - SYSTEM. I want it to be created under my user. I tried using the properties like 'Owner' and 'Name' eg:

```
inParams["Owner"] = ;
inParams["Name"] = ;
```

But they throw a `ManagementException`, "Not Found". Does anyone know how I can do this, or what might be wrong that I'm doing here...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating  a  scheduled job with the [`Win32_ScheduledJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class  is equivalent to create job using the AT command. The AT service normally run under the Local\System account or the NetworkService Account. so when you uses this class your jobs are created using one of these accounts for more info about this topic you can check the *remarks* part of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Understood. Thanks. 
Is there anyway to include a name for the scheduled task using the AT command? Or is there anyway I can run the schtasks command on the remote system using WMI?

Comment: Seems I can use the Win32_Process class to run command line code on the remote machine. It can run schtasks, and with /RU and /RP set it worked. Not the most elegant solution but it has to do. Thanks for the help RRUZ.